# Apache check if user is browsing their home directory

Tags: environment-variables, apache2.4

I for example I've got webserver's root directory */var/www/*.  And user's home directory: */var/www/testuser/*.  I also have basic authorization setted up, so there is a user with username testuser which successfully authorized.  How can I check if the testuser is browsing their home directory by the means of webserver alone?  This is how far I've got:

```
# Getting "testuser" out of "/testuser/echo.php"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(.*)/ URI_HOME=$1

# Getting base64 encoded part out of Authorization header
SetEnvIf Authorization "^Basic (.*)$" X_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

# Converting base64 part to plain text, extracting username and comparing it with home directory 
SetEnvIfExpr "tolower(unbase64(%{ENV:X_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION})) == %{ENV:URI_HOME}" USER_IS_IN_HOME_DIR
```

The major problem is that Apache doesn't have *REMOTE_USER* setted up on the stage when *SetEnvIf* is working.  So I absolutely have to parse *Authorization* header from request.  I almost done it, but I have to cut out part after column to make comparison proper.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to be working:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(.*)/ URI_HOME=$1

SetEnvIf Authorization "^Basic (.*)$" X_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

SetEnvIfExpr "unbase64(%{ENV:X_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION}) -strcmatch '%{ENV:URI_HOME}:*'" USER_IS_IN_HOME_DIR
```

Any ideas how to improve it?